# Make particular checkbox disabled if item at that position is empty

Tags: android

I have a listView which contains a checkbox and two textViews which display two arraylists named as stName and admissionNumber.On more Arraylist I have smsMobileNum . some of the positions don't have smsMobileNum so I want to disable them. it is working but the problem is when I scroll the listView then all checkBoxes becomes disabled. Here is my code

```
public class SmsStudentNameListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

ArrayList<CheckModelClass> smsMobileNum,userIdList;
ArrayList<CheckModelClass> stName,admissionNumber;
ArrayList<String> updatedSmsNumber = new ArrayList<>(), updatedUserId = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
BaseActivity activity;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public SmsStudentNameListAdapter(Context context, BaseActivity activity, ArrayList<CheckModelClass> stName, ArrayList<CheckModelClass> admissionNumber, ArrayList<CheckModelClass> smsMobileNum, ArrayList<CheckModelClass> userIdList, ArrayList<String> updatedSmsNumber, ArrayList<String> updatedUserId) {
    super(context, R.layout.sms_studentlist,stName);
    this.stName = stName;
    this.admissionNumber = admissionNumber;
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.smsMobileNum = smsMobileNum;
    this.userIdList = userIdList;
    this.updatedSmsNumber = updatedSmsNumber;
    this.updatedUserId = updatedUserId;
}

private static class ViewHolder {

    CheckBox checkBox;
    TextView studentName, admissionNum;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_studentlist, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.studentName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        viewHolder.admissionNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    stName.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (updatedUserId.contains(userIdList.get(getPosition).getName()) && updatedSmsNumber.contains(smsMobileNum.get(getPosition).getName())) {

                        } else {

                            updatedUserId.add(userIdList.get(getPosition).getName());
                            updatedSmsNumber.add(smsMobileNum.get(getPosition).getName());
                            }
                        } else {

                            updatedUserId.remove(userIdList.get(getPosition).getName());
                            updatedSmsNumber.remove(smsMobileNum.get(getPosition).getName());
                        }
                    }

        });

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.text1, viewHolder.studentName);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.text2, viewHolder.admissionNum);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.checkbox, viewHolder.checkBox);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.studentName.setText(stName.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.admissionNum.setText(admissionNumber.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(stName.get(position).isSelected());

    if(!smsMobileNum.get(position).getName().equals("null")) {

        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(stName.get(position).isSelected());
    }
    else{

        viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(false);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

}

Comment: Use boolean.if boolean is true then set checkbox true else false.And check boolean false when item is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
// no relevant code

    viewHolder.studentName.setText(stName.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.admissionNum.setText(admissionNumber.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(position);

    boolean isSelected = stName.get(position).isSelected();
    String mobileNum = smsMobileNum.get(position).getName();

    if(mobileNum.equals("null")) {
        viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder.checkBox.setEnabled(true);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(isSelected);
    }
```